Сделать исключение для правила 404
В системном файле htaccess, правило
ErrorDocument 404 /?do=404

Возможно выполнить так, что если к примеру запрос к файлу *-img-*.webp, за место * могут быть только числа...
То есть, если запрос на такой та url, то правило ErrorDocument игнорируется...
